# URL encode ASCII/UTF16 characters

Tags: c#, ascii, urlencode, utf-16

I'm trying to URL-encode some strings, however I have problems with methods provided by the .Net framework.

For instance, I'm trying the encode strings that contain the 'â' character. According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp) for instance, I would expect this caracter to be encoded as '%E2' (and a PHP system I must call expects this too...).

I tried using these methods:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("â");
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("â");
Uri.EscapeUriString("â");
Uri.EscapeDataString("â");
```

However, they all encode this character as:
%C3%A2

I suppose this has something to do with the fact that strings in .Net are UTF-16 encoded. So to avoid this problem, I can write this for instance:

```
"%" + ((int)character).ToString("X")
```

However, I would like to know if the framework already has a built-in method (I can't find any answer here or elsewhere as to why my character is encoded this way)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is *not* that .NET uses UTF-16 encoded strings. The reason is that the [`UrlEncode(string)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses UTF-8 by default, and `%C3%A2` is the correct UTF-8 encoding of `â`:

> The HttpUtility.UrlEncode method uses UTF-8 encoding by default. Therefore, using the UrlEncode method provides the same results as using the UrlEncode method and specifying UTF8 as the second parameter.

If you prefer a different encoding (for example [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or Codepage 1252, where `â` corresponds to `%E2`), you can use another overload that allows you to specify an encoding:

```
var x = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("â", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I didn't notice there were overloads... I give you the answer as you were the first one to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the correct encoding to `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` (`Windows-1252`, `Windows-1254`, `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-9` etc. whichever appropriate)

```
 var s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("â", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));
```